# CICD for microservice architecture

Tags: microservices, cicd

I am trying to setup a proper CICD pipeline for the microservice architecture. We have two types of production environments, one is shared and another one is a dedicated/private environment. Both dedicated and shared are running in Kubernetes. Currently, we are already having about 10 private environments and one shared, we are expecting private environments to grow up to 100 in the next 5 years.

[image]

So, could you please suggest what will be the best practice how to set up the pipeline? Like for example, I can have one pipeline per microservice and deploy environments one by one or all at once. And constantly adding new dedicated environments to the pipeline, or maybe splitting dedicated environments into batches?

Comment: You are talking about a continuous delivery architecture with Kubernetes that would keep scaling?

Comment: @MB yes, exactly

Comment: ArgoCD is a pretty great tool when it comes to continuous delivery. However, there is no in-built support for scaling. But since any deployments/environments can be associated with ArgoCD using CLI commands, you could write scripts that perform the scaling for you.